# How to extract the active code path from a complex algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, extract

I have been puzzled lately by an intruiging idea.

I wonder if there is a (known) method to extract the executed source code from a large complex algorithm. I will try to elaborate this question:

Scenario:
There is this complex algorithm where a large amount of people have worked on for many years. The algorithm creates measurement descriptions for a complex measurement device.

The input for the algorithm is a large set of input parameters, lets call this the recipe. 
Based on this recipe, the algorithm is executed, and the recipe determines which functions, loops and if-then-else constructions are followed within the algorithm. When the algorithm is finished, a set of calculated measurement parameters will form the output. And with these output measurement parameters the device can perform it's measurement.

Now, there is a problem. Since the algorithm has become so complex and large over time, it is very very difficult to find your way in the algorithm when you want to add new functionality for the recipes. Basically a person wants to modify only the functions and code blocks that are affected by its recipe, but he/she has to dig in the whole algorithm and analyze the code to see which code is relevant for his or her recipe, and only after that process new functionality can be added in the right place. Even for simple additions, people tend to get lost in the huge amount of complex code.

Solution: Extract the active code path?
I have been brainstorming on this problem, and I think it would be great if there was a way to process the algorithm with the input parameters (the recipe), and to only extract the active functions and codeblocks into a new set of source files or code structure. I'm actually talking about extracting real source code here.

When the active code is extracted and isolated, this will result in a subset of source code that is only a fraction of the original source code structure, and it will be much easier for the person to analyze the code, understand the code, and make his or her modifications. Eventually the changes could be merged back to the original source code of the algorithm, or maybe the modified extracted source code can also be executed on it's own, as if it is a 'lite' version of the original algorithm.

Extra information:
We are talking about an algorithm with C and C++ code, about 200 files, and maybe 100K lines of code. The code is compiled and build with a custom Visual Studio based build environment.

So...:
I really don't know if this idea is just naive and stupid, or if it is feasible with the right amount of software engineering. I can imagine that there have been more similar situations in the world of software engineering, but I just don't know.

I have quite some experience with software engineering, but definitely not on the level of designing large and complex systems.

I would appreciate any kind of answer, suggestion or comment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have access to the source code? Maybe with code coverage tools that are provided with VS you can accomplish that

Comment: "I wonder if there is a (known) method to extract the..." - pity you insist on a known method, otherwise I'd have had several suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Other naysayers say you can't do this.   I disagree.

A standard static analysis is to determine control and data flow paths through code.  Sometimes such a tool must make assumptions about what might happen, so such analyses tend to be "conservative" and can include more code than the true minimum.  But any elimination of irrelevant code sounds like it will help you.

Furthermore, you could extract the control and data flow paths for a *particular* program input.  Then where the extraction algorithm is unsure about what might happen, it can check what the particular input would have caused to happen.  This gives a more precise result at the price of having to provide valid inputs to the tool.

Finally, using a test coverage tool, you can relatively easily determine the code exercised for a particular input of interest, and the code exercised by another input for case that is not so interesting, and compute the set difference.  This gives code exercised by the interesting case, that is not in common with the uninteresting case.

My company builds build program analysis tools (see my bio).  We do static analysis to extract control and data flow paths on C++ source code, and could fairly easily light up the code involved.  We also make C++ test coverage tools, that can collect the interesting- and uninteresting- sets, and show you the difference superimposed over the source code.

Comment: Visual Studio already has Code Coverage analysis, including the ability to export results to XML [(see here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx).  Plenty of XML diff tools around - easy to write too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid what you try is mathematically impossible. The problem is that this

> **When the algorithm is finished**, a set of calculated measurement parameters will form the output.

is impossible to determine by static code analysis.

What you're running into is essentially a variant of the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) for which has been proven that there can not be an algorithm/program that can determine, if an algorithm passed into it will yield a result in finite time.

Comment: I don't believe the OP has restricted the scope of this to static analysis.  It would be possible in theory if you are allowed to actually run the program, but probably very difficult to the point of being easier just trudging through the difficult and dense code...

Comment: valgrind --tool=callgrind

Comment: @bobah: That will yield only the callgraph for the subset of inputs the program is tested with.

Comment: @datenwolf - "That will yield only the callgraph for the subset of inputs the program is tested with" - which is exactly what the question asks for.